# Calculated Field (Dates)

Tags: list, calculated-column-formula, date

I have a vendor SharePoint list and am trying to do a calculation between two dates to let me know when the next Review Date is. All Vendors have a start date but they don't have an expiration date. How do I do a calculation so that if one of them is Null it calculates the other?

```
=IF([Expiration Date]="","",[Expiration Date]-60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ISBLANK` to check if the field is empty as below

```
IF(ISBLANK([Expiration Date]),"",[Expiration Date]-60)
```